# How do I get max value from column which holds raw JSON objects? Knex

Tags: typescript, postgresql, knex.js

I have a table "myTable", which has the following columns: "id", "raw_json". The values in the "raw_json" column is a big JSON object, which has the property "age".

How would I create a Knex-query that returns the row in the table "myTable", which has the highest raw_json.age value?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You always need start with the SQL query,

Your query should look like:

```sql
Select Max(raw_json->>age) From myTable
```

Then in order to construct it using `knex`:

```js
await knex('myTable').column('Max(raw_json->>age)')
```